# I’m nothing if you stand still

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> I’m felt but not seen
>   Rarely viewed on a screen
>   If you stand still, I’m nothing
>   Keep your pace, I’m nothing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My guess

> Acceleration

I’m felt but not seen

> You can't see acceleration, but you feel the force on your body

Rarely viewed on a screen

> A display will normally show a speedometer, not an accelerometer

If you stand still, I’m nothing

> Stand still (stationary) = no acceleration

Keep your pace, I’m nothing

> No change of speed = no acceleration

Comment: "If you stand still, I’m nothing" is a dubious clue.

Comment: It is actually plain wrong. When a pendulum reaches max height, it stands still but acceleration has reached its maximum as well.

Comment: I edited the answer. I think the clue is correct-ish. It doesn't say "no speed", but "stand still". "Stand still" can be interpreted as being stationary. And something stationary has no acceleration. It might not pass in a physics exam, but I think it's close enough in a puzzle.

Comment: (And I'm not sure I would say a pendulum stands still at its peak. It has a brief moment of zero velocity, but doesn't actually stand still for any measurable amount of time.)